# Garbage collector can't free memory on JBoss 7.1.1 causing Full GC

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jboss, garbage-collection, jvm

I am runing an application on a JBoss 7.1.1 final server, deployed on linux RedHat 5

When I start the server, the used memory is increasing of 2.5M after each launch of the GC, resulting a full GC error in 1 or 2 hours.

This is happening even when the application is not used. GC is running every 10 seconds, regardless of gcInterval argument.

Same application deployed on a windows developpement PC with same JVM and JVM args is working perfectly. GC does not launchs if application is not used. Used memory does not increases after GC's work.

JDK :  1.7.0_55 x64
JVM args :  -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -verbose:gc
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

```
[... Starting JBoss, application is not in use]
[GC 487573K->211517K(585216K), 0,0631790 secs]
[GC 490557K->213509K(585216K), 0,0636420 secs]
[... 10 minutes later]
[GC 585797K->298581K(590848K), 0,0633730 secs]
[GC 587861K->300629K(590848K), 0,0826110 secs]
[Full GC 300629K->255804K(742912K), 1,8318540 secs]
[GC 545084K->258220K(733696K), 0,0096510 secs]
[GC 538284K->260140K(708096K), 0,0139590 secs]
[... 10 minutes later]
[GC 921600K->636408K(967680K), 0,0704860 secs]
[GC 923640K->638440K(967680K), 0,1334640 secs]
[GC 925672K->640472K(967680K), 0,0706450 secs]
```

I have analysed a memory dump and opened it whith MAT, and the big consuming objects are from JBoss and not from the application :

(http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/459885MAT.jpg)

To compare, here is a Visual VM screenshot of the  same application, same JVM and JVM args on a developpement PC under windows. On the left : application not in use, on the right application in use. GC is functionning correctly, runs when necessary, and used amount of memory is stable :

(http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/246156VisualVM.jpg)

Thank you for your help !

Edit : here is detailed gc log :

```
294,409: [GC [PSYoungGen: 131584K->10012K(236544K)] 282316K->160745K(525312K), 0,0257640 secs] [Times: user=0,05 sys=0,00, real=0,03 secs]
300,698: [GC [PSYoungGen: 145692K->13937K(240640K)] 296425K->164670K(529408K), 0,0314710 secs] [Times: user=0,06 sys=0,00, real=0,03 secs]
320,822: [GC [PSYoungGen: 149617K->26904K(234496K)] 300350K->177637K(523264K), 0,0596520 secs] [Times: user=0,11 sys=0,00, real=0,06 secs]
349,830: [GC [PSYoungGen: 167704K->36648K(240128K)] 318437K->187381K(528896K), 0,0856060 secs] [Times: user=0,14 sys=0,00, real=0,09 secs]
400,827: [GC [PSYoungGen: 177448K->50600K(237056K)] 328181K->201333K(525824K), 0,1015110 secs] [Times: user=0,20 sys=0,00, real=0,10 secs]
453,335: [GC [PSYoungGen: 197544K->65128K(239616K)] 348277K->215861K(528384K), 0,1270900 secs] [Times: user=0,24 sys=0,00, real=0,13 secs]
507,227: [GC [PSYoungGen: 212072K->79720K(235520K)] 362805K->230453K(524288K), 0,1589030 secs] [Times: user=0,31 sys=0,00, real=0,16 secs]
557,260: [GC [PSYoungGen: 218472K->93288K(232448K)] 369205K->244021K(521216K), 0,1785030 secs] [Times: user=0,35 sys=0,00, real=0,18 secs]
608,082: [GC [PSYoungGen: 232040K->106920K(233472K)] 382773K->257653K(522240K), 0,2963930 secs] [Times: user=0,40 sys=0,00, real=0,29 secs]
650,849: [GC [PSYoungGen: 224168K->110152K(233472K)] 374901K->268963K(522240K), 0,2341450 secs] [Times: user=0,45 sys=0,00, real=0,23 secs]
693,327: [GC [PSYoungGen: 227400K->103792K(233472K)] 386211K->280538K(522240K), 0,2343350 secs] [Times: user=0,46 sys=0,01, real=0,23 secs]
736,396: [GC [PSYoungGen: 221040K->91616K(233472K)] 397786K->292164K(522240K), 0,2261210 secs] [Times: user=0,43 sys=0,02, real=0,23 secs]
778,381: [GC [PSYoungGen: 208864K->74208K(233472K)] 409412K->303868K(522240K), 0,2123170 secs] [Times: user=0,39 sys=0,03, real=0,21 secs]
821,401: [GC [PSYoungGen: 191456K->58592K(233472K)] 421116K->315572K(522240K), 0,1734580 secs] [Times: user=0,32 sys=0,02, real=0,18 secs]
821,575: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 58592K->18031K(233472K)] [ParOldGen: 256980K->288398K(480768K)] 315572K->306430K(714240K) [PSPermGen: 79966K->79787K(139776K)], 2,7505260 secs] [Times: user=5,14 sys=0,01, real=2,75 secs]
863,389: [GC [PSYoungGen: 135279K->23424K(233472K)] 423678K->318334K(714240K), 0,2504760 secs] [Times: user=0,49 sys=0,00, real=0,25 secs]
906,570: [GC [PSYoungGen: 140672K->24256K(233472K)] 435582K->330022K(714240K), 0,0820190 secs] [Times: user=0,15 sys=0,01, real=0,08 secs]
948,403: [GC [PSYoungGen: 141504K->24192K(233472K)] 447270K->341774K(714240K), 0,0817190 secs] [Times: user=0,15 sys=0,01, real=0,08 secs]
991,577: [GC [PSYoungGen: 141440K->12576K(233472K)] 459022K->353598K(714240K), 0,0888270 secs] [Times: user=0,16 sys=0,01, real=0,09 secs]
1032,722: [GC [PSYoungGen: 129824K->12192K(233472K)] 470846K->365022K(714240K), 0,0605500 secs] [Times: user=0,10 sys=0,01, real=0,06 secs]
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 233472K, used 46338K [0x00000000eaa80000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 117248K, 29% used [0x00000000eaa80000,0x00000000ecbd8be8,0x00000000f1d00000)
  from space 116224K, 10% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f9a68000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 480768K, used 352830K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000dd580000, 0x00000000eaa80000)
  object space 480768K, 73% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000d588fad8,0x00000000dd580000)
 PSPermGen       total 139776K, used 80224K [0x00000000a0000000, 0x00000000a8880000, 0x00000000c0000000)
  object space 139776K, 57% used [0x00000000a0000000,0x00000000a4e58260,0x00000000a8880000)
```

Edit2 : a memory dump reveals the source of the memory leak :

3 616 instances of "com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple", loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x78122a170" occupy 153 506 944 (64,98%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Entry[]", loaded by ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out the solution... this was caused by a bug in the module ironjacamar in JBoss AS version 7.1.1 Final...

To correct, you can patch the module with this one : [ironjacamar-core-impl.jar](https://developer.jboss.org/servlet/JiveServlet/download/759083-66195/ironjacamar-core-impl.jar)

or update JBoss to AS version 7.2.0 + (which you will have to build on your own as it is not distributed anymore)

Another option is to switch to JBoss EAP 6.3 if you can affort the license.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: so it was generating extra java objects?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I see you have an infamous JRE Heap query. Don't you just love these types of issues?!?! ^_^

Its tricky to answer your question not having more info, like that Arunkumar has asked. However I can be general in my response. Usually when setting up your JRE heap config, it should be done within your Wrapper.conf file. Here you should specify your GC method, limits, page sizes etc. Just for demonstration purposes see example below;

```
wrapper.java.additional.4=-XX:SurvivorRatio=6
wrapper.java.additional.5=-XX:MaxPermSize=320m
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Xss256k
wrapper.java.additional.7=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional.8=-XX:+UseParNewGC
wrapper.java.additional.9=-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
wrapper.java.additional.10=-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=31
wrapper.java.additional.11=-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=4m
#wrapper.java.additional.12=-XX:+UseLargePages
#Make sure that the RMI garbage collection is done every hour, not every minute
wrapper.java.additional.12=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.14=-XX:NewSize=836m
wrapper.java.additional.15=-XX:MaxNewSize=836m
```

There is a lot of documentation on the Oracle Website for Java tuning, this link may prove helpful.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm

I hope this helps with your query.

Regards,
Vect0r

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact the issue is a memory leak in database transactions as shown in the memory dump : 3 616 instances of "com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple", loaded by "org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader @ 0x78122a170" occupy 153 506 944 (64,98%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Entry[]", loaded by "<system class loader>"